# Art Guide Theory: Lighting an Game Environment (Objectives, approach/workflow and mood) in PBR

Tags: 3d, lighting, level-design, art

What's the theory behind the Lighting an Game Environment in a Physically Based Renderer?

As far my research, lighting an scene is done with different Rules and Different Ways of Lighting an Scene depending upon the scene.

For an Interior scene - Omni Lights, Area Lights, point Lights and Spot Lights with baking is used to give proper amount of illumination.

[image: Interor Scene]

whereas for an Outdoor Scene - Directional Lights, Area Lights, Point Lights are used to illuminate the scene with baking Lightmaps.

[image]

Usually to Light Individual Objects, 3 point Lighting is used and colors signify the Mood of the Scene.

[image: 3 Point Lighting]

But, the 3 point lighting is unfavorable for Game Environment, So, what's the Good way to start and what are the main objectives in Lighting an Scene?

How Lighting an Scene Contributes to the mood of the scene? like here -

[image: Blacksmith Demo Unity]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Lights in Game Render by Game Engine**, e.g. [Unreal Engine](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DzKu1Y-LlfNQ&ved=0ahUKEwighJDQ3vriAhXCv48KHbReCP0Qo7QBCCcwAA&usg=AOvVaw26PkVSkkCF5v6WbdO8vnOL), [SnowDrop Game Engine](https://youtu.be/jvpbgIN9HE8) and more.A Game World is as huge as a Big Land included many 3D Assets. [Here's PBR study for game](https://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/BrandonHope/20170405/295062/Physically_Based_Rendering_and_Stylization.php). And, **Peachpit, Lighting Principle in Game Design.** Retrieved on http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=174370

**3 Point Light is rarely seen in Game...** Because 3 Point Light called "Studio Light", where can be seen in Photography Studio when a Photographer want to shoot a Fashion, Portrait, Product Photography.

**What makes Game Environment different...Theory of Game Design:** Because of the **Game Mechanics, Game Design (Rules), Level Design** and more.**Game Lighting Technique in Game Design is used to Direct & Attract Players' Eyes about: Where is the Game Objective, Mission, Quest will be on. Where is the direction on Next Level will be.** So, at the end, the Lighting of Game Environment is different than 3-Point Light. The Game Environment will included both Indoor and Outdoor. These Lighting Technique completely been controlled by Level Design matched "game objective, features, Game Mechanics, Game Art-styles, game Flow, levels, and more" at Pre-Production until Production Process. For example, Kratos in God of War 3, he saw a Sun Light surrounding a Treasure (**Light direct Player's eyes look at the point**). Plural Sight. Lighting for Games. Retrived from https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/film-games/understanding-the-importance-of-lighting-for-games